# Display Image Value of first result MVC3 razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, razor

I have this Partial view which is rendered at homepage.  I want to be able to display the picture of the first of the ten results above a list  of the ten results in the view.
I have below in controller

```
    public ActionResult _ChartHome()
    {
        var ChAd = db.Charts
        .Where(v => v.ChOk == true)
        .OrderBy(v => v.ChPosition)
           .Take(10);
        return PartialView(ChAd);
    }
```

View has

```
 <div class="thumb imgblock">   
 <div class="imlk">
 <img src="/images/@d.img?width=286&height=140" class="imlink" />
 </div> 

 @foreach (var d in Model)

 <div class="clear top5widg">
 <p class="musictitle">@d.ChTitle</p>
 <span class="chartno">#@d.ChPosition</span>
 <span class="artistname">By<br/>@d.ChArtist</span> 
 </div>       
  }
 </div>
```

Any help will be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ViewBag to hold the value of the first item

```
public ActionResult _ChartHome()
    {
        var ChAd = db.Charts
        .Where(v => v.ChOk == true)
        .OrderBy(v => v.ChPosition)
           .Take(10);
        ViewBag.First = ChAd.FirstOrDefault();
        return PartialView(ChAd);
    }
```

Do the following for the view code

```
 @{
   var first = (FirstObjectType)ViewBag.First;
}

 <div class="thumb imgblock">   
 <div class="imlk">
 <img src="/images/@first.img?width=286&height=140" class="imlink" />
 </div> 

 @foreach (var d in Model)

 <div class="clear top5widg">
 <p class="musictitle">@d.ChTitle</p>
 <span class="chartno">#@d.ChPosition</span>
 <span class="artistname">By<br/>@d.ChArtist</span> 
 </div>       
  }
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you define your model in the view, then you should be able to just do this:

```
@{
  var imgPath = Model.FirstOrDefault() == null ? "" : Model.FirstOrDefault().img; 
}
@if(imgPath != ""){
   <img src="/images/@imgPath ?width=286&height=140" class="imlink" />
}
```